# Multiple functions to run SQLite queries and save the output to a variable

Tags: java, android

I am building an Android quiz app. I want to display a progress bar showing how many questions a user has answered correctly and how many they have left. Questions are split by difficulty level; easy, medium and hard.

All my questions are stored in an SQLite database. The questions table is made up of three columns:

```
level      question      guessed
```

The `guessed` column is a flag (`1` or `null`) to let me know if the user has guessed the question correctly or not.

To build my progress bar, I'm currently running two pieces of SQL code, for each level, to pull out the total number of questions and the total number of questions guessed correctly. This gives me the numbers I need to build the progress bar. However I am doing it by running 6 individual Java functions, one after the other.

Here is my code:

```
public class DatabaseAccess {

private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;
public static String player_name;

Cursor c = null;

// private constructor so that object creation from outside the class is avoided
public DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

// to return the single instance of database
public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

//to open the database
public void open() {
    this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

//closing the database connection

public void close() {
    if (db != null) {
        this.db.close();
    }
}

public String getEasyMax(String string) {
    c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) FROM player_clues where level = 'easy'", new String[]{});
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String diff = c.getString(0);
        buffer.append("" + diff);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

public String getEasyGuessed(String string) {
    c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) FROM player_clues where level = 'easy' and guessed = 1", new String[]{});
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String diff = c.getString(0);
        buffer.append("" + diff);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

public String getMedGuessed(String string) {
    c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) FROM player_clues where level = 'medium' and guessed = 1", new String[]{});
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String diff = c.getString(0);
        buffer.append("" + diff);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

public String getHardGuessed(String string) {
    c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) FROM player_clues where level = 'hard' and guessed = 1", new String[]{});
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String diff = c.getString(0);
        buffer.append("" + diff);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

public String getMedMax(String string) {
    c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) FROM player_clues where level = 'medium'", new String[]{});
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String diff = c.getString(0);
        buffer.append("" + diff);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

public String getHardMax(String string) {
    c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) FROM player_clues where level = 'hard'", new String[]{});
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String diff = c.getString(0);
        buffer.append("" + diff);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

}
```

In another class, I call on these functions individually and assign the outputs to variables and use them there.

How can I make this more efficient and better?